# Как правильно отнимать дни от текущей даты на php

Tags: php, дата

```
date("j") . ' de ' . date("F") . ' a las 19:05 ';
```

такой код выдает мне **10 de October a las 19:05**

отнимаю 11 дней

```
date("j") -11 de October a las 19:05 . ' de ' . date("F") . ' a las 19:05 ';
```

получаю **-1 de October a las 19:05**

как отнимать дни что бы было в результате

**30 de Septiembre a las 19:05**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$time = strtotime('10 October 2019 -11 days');
echo $date = date("j F Y", $time);
```

Вывод:

```
29 September 2019
```

А дальше уже комбинируйте вывод этой даты как вам угодно

Answer (score 1):

Вы также можете воспользоваться классом [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/class.datetime.php) и его методом `sub()`:

```php
$date = new DateTime();
$date->sub(new DateInterval('P11D'));
echo $date->format('j F, H:i');

// В результате вы получите: 30 September, 11:05
```

[Подробная информация в документации](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/datetime.sub.php)